Is a PhD program the stage at which you define and carve out your own research niche?
Is a PhD the time when you define your academic path, or at least outline what it may become? While researchers have the freedom to change topics throughout their careers, would you recommend striving for coherence to establish a robust academic trajectory?

A PhD is learning how to do research. By the end you perhaps have an idea of directions you can go in. Then the reality of what your next position allows kicks in…

In my experience, I would say no. PhD students who continue to have successful careers in academia (unlike me) generally follow the research program assigned to them by a supervisor. This motivates the supervisor to actually assist them with research (i.e. teach them how to be a researcher), which journals to submit which kinds of papers to, introduce to other researchers (who will be on search committees deciding your future position and / or possible future paper co-authors), etc. Often you can choose to research whatever you want, and you'll get a degree, but you won't be able to stay.

Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/203847/extending-the-phd-project-into-post-doc/203858#203858

This is very hard to answer. There are different disciplinary cultures and very different approaches to PhD programs. A major thing is that when starting a PhD (and in many cases even when finishing), a student doesn't normally have a very good overview and knowledge of their field, at least when it comes to research (not talking about basics here). This means that a PhD student isn't in a very good position to know what would actually work to "strive for coherence to establish a robust academic trajectory".
I think it's important in the first place to keep an open mind. The PhD may turn out to be very different from what the student expected, and they may be attracted to new ideas toward the end of the doctorate. Of course it can't be wrong in itself to do a research project on a topic that you think has the potential to keep you interested in the long run, and where there is enough scope for not only doing a PhD but also for later building a career on it. Chances are in the field of your PhD you will more easily get to know other reseachers, which may be helpful to find a related position or project afterwards. But I'd say that at the beginning of the doctorate, and in very many cases also throughout the whole time, it is so hard to predict where you'd want to go afterwards that I don't think this should be a major consideration dominating other things (like what you just like to do, or with whom you'd like to work).

I would say that you define and carve your own niche during your whole carrier as a scientist, starting even from the master degree.
I fully support your statement about the coherence. There are many practical advantages to be coherent: faster recognition on conferences, higher citations. It doesn't however mean that you shouldn't explore adjacent or even complementary fields. For instance, learn about experiment if you do theoretical science.
However, sometimes some fields come to their decline. Your enthusiasm and curiosity should be strong enough to drive you out of this potential well.

Sometimes yes. Imagining that you will like the PhD research, you could carve out with the help of your advisor(s).
But like others pointed out PhD is rather learning how to do research independently.
But if you're someone outstanding, and survives through the journey despite the hurdles that you would face, and still want to be, yes you can.
I know people who got their PhD and followed with establishing start ups based on it and others who established their research paths and became researchers in it.
